# Add object and immediately take snapshot of canvas - three.js

Tags: image, canvas, download, three.js, snapshot

I have a three.js scene with an object. 
I let the user take a snapshot of what is painted on the canvas.

Although, I want all the snapshots to have also an other object. This object will never appear on the canvas though. So I thought that I will have this object in my scene, but I will position it very far so it will never be visible. But when the user clicks the link to download the snapshot, I will bring the object for some miliseconds in a position where is visible, and when the snapshot of the canvas is done I will move it again vary far.

```
    document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
      appearMesh();
      downloadCanvas(this , "screenshot");
      disappearMesh();

    }, false);

    function downloadCanvas(link,  filename) {

      link.href = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].toDataURL();
      link.download = filename;

    };
```

That doesn't work though : http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/21/

Nothing appears in the image.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: FYI `mesh.visible = false` is used to toggle visibility.

Comment: yes I know that attribute. there are many ways to throw an object out of the scene. which is the most efficient is a good question. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should call a render after you move the object:

```
function appearMesh(){
    meshToAppear.position.x = 0;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
function disappearMesh(){
    meshToAppear.position.x = 1000;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking something like that right now. I am trying it and 'll get back.